# QED applied to two charged particles

Tags: photons, charge, quantum-electrodynamics, coulombs-law, virtual-particles

To get the hang of how bosons actually work, could someone please provide me (the real question being, is it even possible to provide me) with a complete description of how photons are behaving and what is going where when, say, two oppositely charged particles a placed some distance apart? My purpose for asking this question is hoping to develop some intuition as to how QFT works.

Comment: Voting to close as unclear - what exactly do you want computed or explained within the framework of QFT? When you say "how QFT works", what aspect of it? What is your knowledge of QFT? Are you asking how the $r^{-2}$ force comes out of QFT for two charges?

Comment: My knowledge of QFT is next to zero. I just know that it predicts that all fundamental forces arise due to interaction of bosons in their respective fields. So I want to view the described situation in a purely quantum mechanical model where the electromagnetic force between the particles is accounted for by movement of photons or excitations in the electromagnetic field.

Comment: Then as I suspected, you essentially want to see how $1/r^2$ comes out of quantum electrodynamics?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is too broad.

Answer (score 2):

To recover the force arising between two charged particles in quantum electrodynamics, we consider the tree level diagram contributing to $e^- e^- \to e^- e^-$ scattering, given by,

[image]

The amplitude is given by applying the Feynman rules, yielding,

$$\mathcal M \sim e^2 \frac{[\bar u(p')\gamma^\mu u(p)][\bar u(q')\gamma_\mu u(q)]}{(p'-p)^2}$$

up to some signs and factors of $i$ depending on conventions. In the non-relativistic limit, $p \to (m,\vec p)$, and we can recover the non-relativistic limit of a spinor, which is a solution to Dirac's equation. Following non-relativistic quantum mechanics wherein to first order the amplitude is the Fourier transform of the potential, we perform an inverse transform to yield,

$$V(r) = \frac{e^2}{4\pi r}$$

which yields the $r^{-2}$ behaviour in the Coulomb force as expected.